# When Does Object Actually Gets Destroyed in C++? What does delete(ptr) Do?

Tags: c++, object, delete-operator

The program without `delete` works perfectly.  However, on using `delete`, I am not getting any result.  The program is terminating abruptly.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Book
{
  string *title;
  int *price,*stock;

public:
  Book()
  {
    title=new string();
    price=new int();
    stock=new int();
  }

  Book(string n,int p,int s)
  {    
     title=new string(n);
     price=new int(p);
     stock=new int(s);
  }

  ~Book()
  {
     cout<<"Object Destroyed"<<endl;
     // delete (title);  Using Delete i am getting Wrong Results.
     // delete (price);
     // delete (stock);
  }

  void inst();
  void buy();
  void display();
};

void Book::display()
{
  cout<<"Title :"<<*title;
  cout<<" Price is :"<<*price;
  cout<<" Stock is :"<<*stock;
  cout<<endl;
}

int main()
{
  Book a[2];

  for(int x=0;x<2;x++)
  {
    string title;
    int p,s;
    cout<<"Enter title,price,stock respectively"<<endl;
    cin>>title;
    cin>>p;
    cin>>s;
    a[x]=Book(title,p,s);
  }

  for(int x=0;x<2;x++)
    a[x].display();
}
```

FOLLOWING IS THE OUTPUT :

```
Enter title,price,stock respectively
C++
120
2
Object Destroyed
Enter title,price,stock respectively
JAVA
150
5
Object Destroyed
Title :C++   Price is :120    Stock is :2
Title :JAVA  Price is :150    Stock is :5
Object Destroyed
Object Destroyed
```

Why Am I getting `Object Destroyed` after every input?

Comment: Slightly related, prefer value semantics. There is no need here for your members to be pointers.

Comment: Did you carefully read a good [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) book ?

Comment: Read up on "the rule of three". Also, [mcve].

Comment: I suspect the reason you are getting crashes with `delete` is that you are not respecting the [rule of 0/3/5](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) which wouldn't be an issue if you used value semantics. To fix the problem with the current architecture (if that's the problem), implement a copy constructor and copy assignment operator.

Comment: This line is responsible for the calls of destructor: `a[x] = Book(title, p, s);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `Book` is not following the [Rule of 3/5/0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

You have a default constructor and a conversion constructor to allocate memory, and a destructor to free memory, but you do not have a copy constructor or a copy assignment operator (or a move constructor or a move assignment operator).  As such, the compiler will provide implicit implementations that shallow-copy the pointers as-is from one object to another, not make deep-copies of the data being pointed at.

This statement:

```
Book a[2];
```

Is default-constructing 2 `Book` objects, and allocating data for each one.

This statement:

```
a[x]=Book(title,p,s);
```

Is constructing a *temporary* `Book` object for the user's input, then copy-assigning that temporary to an existing object in the array, and then finally destructing the temporary, freeing the memory that it was pointing at.

The compiler-generated copy assignment operator shallow-copies the pointers to the other object (leaking the memory that it was already pointing at), so when the temporary frees the memory, the pointers in the assigned-to object are left dangling.  Your code then crashes when `display()` tries to access invalid memory.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Book
{
  string *title;
  int *price, *stock;

public:
  Book() :
    title(new string()),
    price(new int()),
    stock(new int())
  {
  }

  Book(const Book &src) :
    title(new string(*src.title)),
    price(new int(*src.price)),
    stock(new int(*src.stock))
  {
  }

  // C++11 and later only...
  Book(Book &&src) :
    title(nullptr),
    price(nullptr),
    stock(nullptr)
  {
    swap(title, src.title);
    swap(price, src.price);
    swap(stock, src.stock);
  }

  Book(string n, int p, int s) :
    title(new string(n)),
    price(new int(p)),
    stock(new int(s))
  {    
  }

  ~Book()
  {
     delete title;
     delete price;
     delete stock;
  }

  Book& operator=(const Book &rhs)
  {
    if (&rhs != this)
    {
      Book tmp(rhs);
      swap(title, tmp.title);
      swap(price, tmp.price);
      swap(stock, tmp.stock);
    }
    return *this;
  }

  // C++11 and later only...
  Book& operator=(Book &&rhs)
  {
    swap(title, rhs.title);
    swap(price, rhs.price);
    swap(stock, rhs.stock);
    return *this;
  }

  ...

  void display();
};

void Book::display()
{
  cout << "Title :" << *title;
  cout << " Price is :" << *price;
  cout << " Stock is :" << *stock;
  cout << endl;
}
```

The simpler solution is to strive for the Rule of Zero - write code that does not require custom copy/move constructors, copy/move operators, or a destructor.  Let the compiler-generated implementations do all of the necessary work for you:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Book
{
  string title;
  int price, stock;

public:
  Book() :
    title(), price(0), stock(0)
  {
  }

  Book(string n, int p, int s) :
    title(n), price(p), stock(s)
  {    
  }

  ...

  void display();
};

void Book::display()
{
  cout << "Title :" << title;
  cout << " Price is :" << price;
  cout << " Stock is :" << stock;
  cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `a[x]=Book(title,p,s)` the program performs two steps:

1. Create an instance of Book by using your constructor. Let’s call this instance „alpha“
2. Create a new instance of Book (a[x]) by using a copy constructor. Let’s call this instance „beta“

When reaching the end of the for brackets, the life line of „alpha“ ends and the destructor is called.

Remember the copy constructor? Using this the pointers are copied. No new instances of the member variables are created. Repugnant the delete part, those member variables are deleted wenn the life line of „alpha“ ends and the corresponding destructor is called. Trying to access the deleted variables still referenced by the pointers of „beta“ causes the crash.

There are multiple solutions to overcome the problem as highlighted in the comments:

1. Don‘t use pointers
2. Implement a copy constructor

Comment: `a[x]=...` does not invoke the *copy constructor*, since the object is already constructed. It invokes the *copy assignment* operator instead (or maybe the *move assignment operator* in C++11, since the right side is an rvalue).